# Как можно расширить область нажатия у ссылки?

Tags: html, css, scss

Есть такое меню:

html

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__top">
        <div class="container header__container">
            <nav class="header__menu menu">
                <ul class="menu__list">
                    <li class="menu__list-item list-item__location"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Москва</a></li>
                    <ul class="menu-list__navigation">
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">О нас</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Доставка</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Подключение техники</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Доп. сервис</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Наши гарантии</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Почему мы?</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Оставить обращение</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li class="menu__list-item list-item__user"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

scss

```
.header {
    &__container {
    }

    &__top {
        border-bottom: 1px solid $backgroundColor;
    }

    &__menu {
    }
}

.menu {
    &__list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 40px;
        color: $mainTextColor;
    }

    &__list-item {
    }

    &__link {
        color: $mainTextColor;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        &:visited {
            color: $mainTextColor;
        }
        &:hover,
        &:active {
            color: $activeColor;
        }
    }
}
.list-item {
    &__location {
        position: relative;
        &::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: url(@img/header/location.svg);
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            max-width: 14px;
            max-height: 14px;
            right: 25px;
        }
    }

    &__user {
        position: relative;
        &::before {
            content: url(@img/header/user.svg);
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            max-width: 14px;
            max-height: 14px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
        }
    }
}
.menu-list {
    &__navigation {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;

        > .menu__list-item {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

`@img` это псевдоним (алиас) для `../images`. В общем, получается такое меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что наведение на ссылку работает не на всем тексте пунктов. `hover` и `cursor: pointer` отрабатывают только, когда курсор оказывается в середине слова. Как расширить область нажатия на ссылку? И еще хотелось бы, чтобы ссылки работали и при наведении на `::before`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header__top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu__link {
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu__link:visited {
  color: red;
}

.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link:active {
  color: blue;
}

.list-item__location {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item__location::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: url(@img/header/location.svg);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 14px;
  max-height: 14px;
  right: 25px;
}

.list-item__user {
  position: relative;
}

.list-item__user::before {
  content: url(@img/header/user.svg);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 14px;
  max-height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}

.menu-list__navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu-list__navigation>.menu__list-item {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__top">
    <div class="container header__container">
      <nav class="header__menu menu">
        <ul class="menu__list">
          <li class="menu__list-item list-item__location"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Москва</a></li>
          <ul class="menu-list__navigation">
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">О нас</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Доставка</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Оплата</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Подключение техники</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Доп. сервис</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Наши гарантии</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Почему мы?</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Оставить обращение</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li class="menu__list-item list-item__user"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Добавьте верхний и нижний padding для ссылок .menu__link.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]